# Indentation in Drupal 8 form

Tags: theming, 8

I have a drupal 8 form as follows:

```
   $form['extra_fields']['email'] = [
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#options' => ['email' => 'email'],
        '#title' => $this->t('Email')
    ];

   $form['email']['required'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#options' => array(0 => $this->t('Required'), 1 => $this->t('Not Required')),
    );
```

which shows up as:

[image: indent]

I would like to have the radios a bit indented. Is it possible to achieve this? Also, how to make the radio buttons inline?

Thanks.

Comment: To make radio buttons inline, use the following in the element definition: `'#attributes' => ['class' => ['container-inline']],`. To have then indented you need to define another class and provide the required CSS yourself.

Answer (score 3):

### Assuming you built this form programmatically (custom module):

#### Wrap your radios field inside a class using #prefix and #suffix

```
   $form['email']['required'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#options' => array(0 => $this->t('Required'), 1 => $this->t('Not Required')),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="indent">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
```

#### Use CSS to alter the look.

Create a CSS file.

**my_module/css/myform.css**

> a bit indented

```
.indent {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

> make the radio buttons inline?

```
.indent .js-form-type-radio {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Create a library

**my_module/my_module.libraries.yml**

```
form-stuff:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/myform.css: {}
```

#### Attach library to your form so it loads your CSS

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/form-stuff';
```